# Problems with confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Is it possible to use `function` to create an equation which will produce a normal distribution and simultaneously produce a 95% confidence interval of said data? I know that I can use `rnorm(n,mean,sd)` to generate a random normal distribution but how do I get the output to tell me the confidence interval?

I have attempted `sample_CI<- function(n,j,k){list(g<-rnorm(n, mean=j, sd=k), confint(g, level=.95))}`.

All help appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what kind of output you want. Could you give more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be this what you were looking for:

```
sample_CI <- function(n,j,k){
  error <- qnorm(0.975)*k/sqrt(n)
  left <- j-error
  right <- j+error
  paste("[",round(left,4)," ; ",round(right,4),"]")
}
sample_CI(1000,2,4)
```

Comment: Why ``qnorm`` instead of ``rnorm``? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Matlabrookie -  `qnorm()` produces the Z score associated with the area under the curve specified in the first argument to the function. In the case of @Bram's code, `qnorm(0.975)` = 1.959964, the Z score for the upper bound of the 95% confidence interval.  In contrast, `rnorm(n)` returns  *n* observations randomly drawn from a normal distribution.

Comment: @LenGreski To produce a t score would qnorm also be used?

Comment: @Matlabrookie - For Student's t, the quantile function is [`qt(p,df)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TDist.html), where `p` represents the desired probability, and `df` represents the number of degrees of freedom. As `df` approaches infinity, `qt()` approaches `qnorm()`

Comment: @LenGreski I now want to use ``replicate()`` to produce 1000 different confidence intervals and then check to see how many my mean is contained in. Using the ``qnorm`` function and ``replicate()`` together returns the same confidence interval 1000 times. Should I revert to ``rnorm``? and what should I use instead of ``qt(p,df)``

Comment: @Matlabrookie - Please post another question, including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll answer it. I don't have enough context to understand how you plan to generate and use  the 1,000 confidence intervals to provide a reasonable answer to your question.